# How to run shell script file within the jenkins shared libary

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-shared-libraries

I'd like to execute a shell file from within the shared library itself.

here is the path of the file:

```
libraryFoo/resources/foo.sh
```

my PipelineUtils package path within the library: `libraryFoo/src/f1.org.pipeline/PipelineUtils`

```
class PipelineUtils implements Serializable {
   ...
   def shell() {
    pipeline.sh(
            script: resources/foo.sh,
            returnStdout: true
    )
  }
}
```

and it is implemented in the pipeline:

```
@Library('libraryFoo') _
import f1.org.pipeline.PipelineUtils

...

    stage('Tag SCM') {
        def utils = new PipelineUtils()
        utils.shell()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to read files from the resources folder of your shared library you will need to use a designated step created exactly for this called [libraryResource](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps-global-lib/#libraryresource-load-a-resource-file-from-a-shared-library):

> **`libraryResource`**: Load a resource file from a shared library
> Reads a resource from a shared library and returns its content as a plain string.
>
> - **resource**
>   Relative (/-separated) path to a resource in a shared library's **/resources** folder.
> - **encoding** (optional)
>   The encoding to use when reading the resource. If left blank, the platform default encoding will be used. Binary files can be read into a Base64-encoded string by specifying "Base64" as the encoding.

So in your case you can use it to load the script and run it using the `sh` step, assuming `pipeline` is your object that holds the script context it will look like:

```groovy
class PipelineUtils implements Serializable {
   ...
def shell() {
   pipeline.sh(
      // Load the script as string and run using sh step
      script: pipeline.libraryResource('foo.sh'),
              returnStdout: true
   )
}
```

Alternatively you can also load the script and rewrite it to a local file if you need it for future use:

```groovy
class PipelineUtils implements Serializable {
   ...
def shell() {
   // Load  the file from resources folder and recreate it locally
   def fileContent = pipeline.libraryResource('foo.sh')
   pipeline.writeFile(file: 'localFile.sh`, text: fileContent)

   pipeline.sh(
       // Use the file from the file System
       ...
   )
}
```